# Can't access the data property of the response in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, console.log

I have two pages, **register** and **status**. From the register page, I submit a form and when I get the response I want to send it to the status page and access some of the properties of the object.

```
    const register = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/register", {
        name : name,
        NID : NID,
        birth : birth,
        phone : phone,
        gender : gender,
        center : center,
        address : address
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setResponse(response.data.NID);
    });
    e.target.reset();
};
```

The post request is successful every time in the MySQL database. But when I console log the response.data I don't get the data properties.
[image]

The backend:

```
    app.post("/register", (req, res) => {

  const name = req.body.name;
  const NID = req.body.NID;
  const birth = req.body.birth;
  const phone = req.body.phone;
  const gender = req.body.gender;
  const center = req.body.center;
  const address = req.body.address;

  db.query(
    "insert into register (name, NID, birth, phone, gender, center, address) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
    [name, NID, birth, phone, gender, center, address],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        res.send(result);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Also, on rendering {response.data.name} I get an error.

Comment: It's an off-topic comment, but you can make your code more concise if you 1) on the client when doing axios request simply do this: `Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/register", { name, NID, etc.` -- if the property name is the same as the variable, you can use shorthand notation -- there's no reason to repeat like `name: name`. 2) in the server code you can use object destructuring: `const { name, NID, etc. } = req.body;`

Comment: Thank you so much for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're logging is what your server is returning as a response. You'll need to return what you need in the response from your backend app. So instead of `res.send(result)` where `result` is the result of the db query, call `res.send` with whatever data you want to send to the frontend.

Or if what you need is in the request parameters, just wait for the request to succeed (like in your code sample) and use the request parameters. I.e. instead of `setResponse(response.data.NID)` use `setResponse(NID)` - you already have "NID" as a variable in your code sample.

Comment: I actually want to send the entire object in frontend and then access the properties.
I followed this repo: https://github.com/suppaGonzal0/Simple-CRUD-React-Node-MySQL/blob/main/server/index.js
It worked for me in another project but even though I did the same thing it is not working.

Comment: What object? You mean an object with `{ name, NID ... }`? Then do `res.send({ name, NID, birth, phone, gender, center, address })`.

Comment: I can try that but it really worked like this in another project. You can also check out the repo. I did res.send(result) in backend and in the frontend I console.log(response.data) and all properties were shown in the console tab. Why is it not working in this case?

Comment: Well, looks like the result of the db query is `{ affectedRows: 1, fieldCount: 0, ... }` as is logged in the frontend. You can see for yourself what the response data will be by doing `console.log(result)` in backend before `res.send(result)`.

Comment: Yes exactly, can you tell me why is that happing? What can I change in my code to get the result which will be an array of the properties I submited?

Comment: `res.send({ name, NID, birth, phone, gender, center, address })` instead of `res.send(result)`. The `result` variable contains what the db query returns, which apparently is not what you want. The result of an INSERT query is different from a SELECT query, which is probably what is tripping you up here.

Comment: Yes, I totally get you. Thank you for your solution. I will definitely try it. But I just wanted to know why does the result not have the data property. Every time I came across such scenario I always used the response.data property. Is there a problem with my dependencies?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240221/discussion-between-evsheino-and-suppagonzalo).

Answer (score 0):

What do your backend returns ? Is it just a response.status 201 ? Is the body empty ?
You should check in the Network tab of the devtools what happens when you hit that endpoint.

HTTP Status codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: I added the backend. When I console.log the response I can't view the data property. It's there but it's just data{...} and if I console log the response.data I get no properties of the object I received as the response.